# New razor view inside controller folder

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

I just started working with Visual Studio 2019. Creating a .net core web app.
After creating a controller, when I right-click on an action to create a corresponding view, the new view is getting created inside the Controllers folder instead of inside View/{ControllerName} folder.

Has anyone faced this before? Is this something new with VS 2019? Is there some setting that needs to be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not select (Razor View - Empty) select Razor View after that just create View.